# SO Teams ad shows a higher price than expected (the real price is lower!)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm thinking about creating a SO Teams for 5 users. When looking at [/pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/pricing) page, we first see:

[image]

which makes believe, at first sight, that it's going to be 25$/mo.

In fact it's only 10$/mo since *"Teams start at $10 per month and include your first 10 users."*

It's the first time I see a marketing plan in which **the advertised price in big font size** is much higher than the real price :)

Is it a wanted effect, so that when we look at the small asterisk, we have a *"Oh it's lower than what I thought!"* effect?

It's probably none of my business, but shouldn't it be advertised "starting at $2 per user" instead of "$5 per user" which is wrong if size < 10?

Comment: Well, _starting at $2 per user_ is suggestive too. If you start a 100 user team, the price will be a lot closer to $500 than $200. They could reword it, but not to that, possibly they could just add _first 10 users $10_.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You're right, it makes sense. It depends on the average size of SO Teams potential customers. I thought many people interested in Teams might have small size, but this is just pure guess.

Comment: I like the way atlassian advertises their products.  They just say for teams of upto 10 its 10 bucks period...anything else see the pricing plan (and they link you to prices above 10 users).

Comment: Oh, the good old * note. In the * note, it says it clearly. The price plan is flat 10/month for the first 10, afterwards is 5 for each aditional user.

Comment: "Starting at $10/mo" is usually how these things are phrased.

Comment: I personally would prefer a combination of what Draco18s and ErikvonAsmuth said: "Starting at $10/mo, first 10 users included" or something in that way.

Comment: In the [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), the phrasing is exactly as @Draco18s suggests.

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a way to make "two for a nickel, three for a dime" pricing less confusing in a compact ad line. Just use more words and spell it all out.